# How to connect this model association both belongs_to_through and belongs_to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, model-associations

Here are my models:

```
**Resource**
has_many :users, :through => :kits
has_many :kits

**User**
has_many :resources, :through => :kits
has_many :kits

**Kits**
belongs_to :resource
belongs_to :user
```

Users in the application can add resources to their kits by clicking on them. Then I can find out which resource a User has by doing:

```
@user.resources
```

Now a user can also submit a resource for approval.  I want to track which user submitted which resource. How can I do this so that I can do the following:

**Resource Controller**

```
def create
current_user.resources.create(params[:resource])
end
```

I would like to be able to do something like:

```
@user.submitted_resources.count
```

Comment: To clarify, you want a count of all the resources a User has created (as in `ResourceController#create`)?

Comment: Do you have a column on the Resource model that holds the User id of the creator?

Comment: For now I made one called submitter_id but I don't know how to associate in the Rails way

Comment: That works just fine, check the answer I posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given models with the following associations (and the necessary tables, columns, etc.):

```
**Resource**
has_many :users, :through => :kits
has_many :kits
belongs_to :submitter, class_name: "User"

**User**
has_many :resources, :through => :kits
has_many :kits
has_many :submitted_resources, class_name: "Resource", foreign_key: "submitter_id"

**Kits**
belongs_to :resource
belongs_to :user
```

Note the added `has_many :submitted_resources, class_name: "Resource", foreign_key: "submitter_id"` on the `User` model. This assumes that there is a column on the `Resources` table named `submitter_id` (which you said you had added). After adding this association, you can reference all the resources a `User` has submitted with the `User#submitted_resources` method (i.e. `@user.submitted_resources.count`).

I also added the `belongs_to :submitter, class_name: "User"` association to your `Resource` model, which allows for easy referencing the `User` that created the record, but it isn't necessary to accomplish what you asked.

Comment: Hi Colin thanks very much for this. I will give it a shot and get back to you. If it works(which it will)then I will accept the answer and award you the well deserved points.